# Iterate textboxes in order by name, inside a tab control

Tags: c#, textbox, iteration, tabcontrol

I have a bunch of textboxes, about 150 to be exact.  They are inside different tabs of a tab control, and are not in order by name on screen.  They are named simply textBox1, textBox2, textBox3...  I would like to be able to iterate them in order by name and not by how they appear on the form.  How would I got about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetChildrenRecursive(Control parent)
{
    var controls = new List<Control>();
    foreach(Control child in parent.Controls)
        controls.AddRange(GetChildrenRecursive(child));
    controls.Add(parent); //fix
    return controls;
}

TextBox[] textboxes = GetChildrenRecursive(this)
       .OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: When I tried this there doesn't end up being anything in the textboxes array.

Comment: Oh, just saw your update, its strange though, it goes from textBox1 to textBox10 goes in order till the end then goes back to textBox2 up to textBox9...

Comment: Because its compared as a strings. You can use something like this: OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Name.Replace("textBox", ""))

Comment: I changed it to from an array to a list.  Then am using the sort method on the names.  Thanks a lot for your help.